# value from one table pass as column to another table in snowflake

Tags: sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Looking for variable value substitution into query
I have a table where my column name defined
as select col_name from table1; it gives output as employee_name

This value  have to pass as column name into employee table like
select tbl1.col_name as Name,age from employee
left join (select col_name from table1) as tbl
where tbl1.col_name ='John'

It is giving result as
[image: Name , age employee_name, 12]

But I expect output as
[image: Name , age John , 12]

Comment: You can only do this dynamically in code that writes and then executes the sql based on the results of the first query. So a stored procedure or snowflake script block using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` command or in a language of your choice like python or what-have-you.